# Pipe separated output using fprintf...Optimized way

Tags: c

I have to modify a existing code where there are many fprintf statements like this

```
       fprintf (stdout, "%-30.30s",reason);
```

But now if user passed "T" in main argument then I will print the output separared by a delimiter "|"

I have several fprint in my file.

Currently I have taken a flag which sets to true if user wants pipe separated output.

```
    if(flag)
          fprintf (stdout, "%-30.30s|",reason);
    else
          fprintf (stdout, "%-30.30s",reason);
```

Please suggest me if there is any other better approach to acheive this. Please note that I have several fprintf's scattered in my file.

Thanks !!!

Comment: I doubt there's any other way, what's the problem with the way you're doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *separator = flag ? "|" : "";

fprintf(stdout, "%-30.30s%s", reason, separator);
```

Comment: "Optimised" for reduced duplication. I haven't measured any other properties.

Comment: Another option is to use `char` and `%c` format. It is probably slightly faster than `%s`, because the latter has to check for `\0`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin you can't print a zero-length character. You could add a character that isn't printable, but that might confuse downstream tools.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner:

```
fprintf (stdout, "%-30.30s%c",reason,(flag?'|':'\0'));
```

For multiple fprintf's in your code, you could simply write a macro or an inline function, which prints based on a set of arguments. Write a wrapper function and call that wrapper function with valid arguments. Depending on your program specifications(which is not clear from your question) you will have to find the best way to write a wrapper function.

For eg:

put all fprintf stuffs in a wrapper function like this and call only with the flag and the case no.

```
//Illustrative purposes only
void wrapper(int flag, int caseno,char* reason)
{
if(reason!=NULL)
switch(caseno)
{
case 1:
   fprintf(stdout,"xyz%s",reason);
   break;
case 2:
   fprintf(stdout,"abc%s",reason);
   break;
...
}

fprintf (stdout, "%c",(flag?'|':'\0'));

return;
}
```

Since you are writing errors to o/p I would suggest using `stderr` instead of `stdout`.